# SQL Server 2008 Distinct Rows Grouping

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using Microsoft Sql Server 2008.
with this below query certain rows are fetched with , but it is possible to arrange rows with distinct rows ordered from every table.

```
select id1,c1,id2,c2,id3,c3
from t1 
left join t2 on t2.fk = t1.pk
left join t3 on t3.fk = t1.pk
order by id3
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort on id1, id2 and id3

EDIT: Updated with additional sequencing field

```
;WITH data AS
(
    select id1,c1,id2,c2,id3,c3, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id1, id2 ORDER BY id2) as id2seq,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id1, id2, id3 ORDER BY id3) as id3seq    
    from t1   
    left join t2 on t2.fk = t1.pk  
    left join t3 on t3.fk = t1.pk  
)
select id1, c1, id2, c2, id3, c3
from data
order by id1, id2seq, id3seq
```

**EDIT**: Completed query for exact results

```
;with data as( 
    select pid 
        , pname 
        , cid 
        , cname 
    from #t1 t1 
    left join #t2 t2 on t2.fk_pid = t1.pid 
), cte AS 
( 
    select pid 
          , eid 
          , ename 
    from #t1 t1 
         left join #t3 t3 on t3.fk_pid = t1.pid
), combine AS
(
    select d.pid 
        , pname 
        , cid 
        , cname
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by d.pid, cid order by cid) as seq 
        , eid 
        , ename 
      from data d join cte c on d.pid = c.pid 
) 
select pid, pname, cid, cname, eid, ename 
from combine 
order by pid, seq, cid
```

Comment: yeah, i tried tat too already, but i am getting the needed output, see column2, i need to order distinct rows first

Comment: I see the problem.  Is there not something that identify the first 5 from id2 to make it different from the second 5?  If not, then they should belong together, but it sould appear from your illustration that there is another key that can indicate first vs second group

Comment: yes, 5 from id2 is PK of that table and it is joined with 1 from id1. id1,c1 - table1, id2,c2 - table2, id3,c3 - table3. table2 and table3 are joined by id1 from table1. Hope u understood.

Comment: I updated the post to include a sequence number generated that will help sort the data in correct order.

Comment: hi sorry i dint noticed the last 2 columns, only the second set are getting ordered, i tried with different ranking functions but of no use. any other methods.

Comment: That is probably caused by the second ROW_NUMBER function.  Try using this function as ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id1, id3 ORDER BY id3)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6485/discussion-between-m-bharni-dharan-and-leons)

Comment: Updated with a sql statement that works for the expected results